# Parsing a semi colon delimited String

Tags: vb.net

I am required to write a program for visual basic 2008 in which I will process a delimited string which is formatted as such:

```
Word;Submitter;CorrectGuesses;IncorrectGuesses
```

I need to be able to edit the number of Correct or incorrect guesses when a matching value is found for both the word and the submitter. I believe that to do this I may need to use a combination of InStr and Mid functions, however I have very little knowledge of how these work.

If someone could help explain these functions specifically in this context, and/or possibly provide code that would achieve this, preferably well commented so I can see how the functions are working. To help me complete the final part of this project.

Comment: Your ide does really not matter in the tags.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what difficulties did you encounter with your code that you would like to discuss? At its current stage your question looks more like a specification for some program that needs to be written rather than a question from someone posting on an internet forum after having encountered some specific programming related difficulty with his code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added more code to tinstaafi's answer. However, I would like to highlight the fact that he has solved the crux of the problem.

```
Dim Correct as Integer
Dim InCorrect as Integer

Dim MyString As String = "Word;Submitter;CorrectGuesses;IncorrectGuesses"
Dim MyStringSplit() As String = MyString.Split(";")

Correct = MyStringSplit(2) 
InCorrect = MyStringSplit(3) 
' if answer is correct
    Correct = Correct + 1

'if answer is incorrect
    InCorrect = InCorrect + 1

MyStringSplit(2) = CStr(Correct)
MyStringSplit(3) = CStr(InCorrect)

Dim MYNewString As String = String.Join(";", MyStringSplit)
```

Answer (score 3):

The split function is probably your best option:

```
    Dim MyString As String = "Word;Submitter;CorrectGuesses;IncorrectGuesses"
    Dim MyStringSplit() As String = MyString.Split(";")
```

Then after editing the strings you can join them back together like this:

```
    Dim MYNewString As String = String.Join(";", MyStringSplit)
```